# How do you access the "code" property of a FirebaseError in AngularFire / TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

[FirebaseError has a "code" property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.FirebaseError), but how do you read it in the catch method of a promise? The following throws a TypeScript error of: `Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.`

```
this.af.database
.object(`/some/path`)
.set(newObj)
.then(data => {
  console.log('success');
})
.catch(err => {
  // Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.
  console.log(`code`, err.code);
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Another resolution, you can try import global FirebaseError from '@firebase/util' package and check using type guard as below.

```
import { FirebaseError } from '@firebase/util'

try {
    // Some firebase functions
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
} catch (error: unknown) {
   if (error instanceof FirebaseError) {
      console.error(error.code)
   }
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm using firebase sdk version 9.x

Comment: What if you want to do certain thing based on the code value like this: if(error.code === something){). Where do I get the values of "something"

Answer (score 9):

To access the code property, you need to import firebase and give your error the firebase.FirebaseError type, like so:

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import firebase from 'firebase';

...

constructor(
  private af: AngularFire
) {}

...

this.af.database
.object(`/some/path`)
.set(newObj)
.then(data => {
  console.log('success');
})
.catch( (err: firebase.FirebaseError) => {
  // Give your error the firebase.FirebaseError type and
  // you'll have access to all the FirebaseError properties
  console.log(`code`, err.code);
  console.log(`message`, err.message);
  console.log(`name`, err.name);
  console.log(`stack`, err.stack);
});
```

Comment: thanks! where can you find more documentation for the latest angularfire? it's a pain in the ass to work with

Answer (score 3):

While Patrickmcd's workaround will work. It is not an ideal solution. You should not be relying on importing the firebase object to have the correct type on the Error Object. This defeats the point of the Angular Fire Module.
It also adds a lot of unnecessary bulk into your application.
Please see the bug report here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/666

It is planned to be fixed in beta 7

Using Bracket Notation and String Literals My workaround does not require you to import the Firebase library.

See an example below

```
 this.af.auth.login({
      email: this.userEmail,
      password: this.userPassword
    }).catch(error => {
      // Returns the firebase Error Code documented here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error
      console.log(error['code']);
      // Returns the fire base message associated with the Error Code
      console.log(error['message']);

      // Show failed login validation
      this.loginFailed = true;

    });
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

If you're using individual Firebase modules, each module has an error type.

```
import { FirestoreError } from 'firebase/firestore'

.catch( (err: FirestoreError) => {
  // Give your error the firebase.firestore.Error type and
  // you'll have access to all the Error properties
  console.log(`code`, err.code);
  console.log(`message`, err.message);
  console.log(`name`, err.name);
  console.log(`stack`, err.stack);
});
```